# Race between pool requests in Guzzle

Tags: guzzle, guzzle6

I'm doing mutiple api concurrent requests using guzzle Pool.
Everything's working fine.

But I want to stop/avoid all requests if any of the requests responded. That is, I want to do some race between the requests. Is it possible using Guzzle in laravel?

Here's what I've done so far:

```
        $requests = function(array $urls){

                foreach ($urls as $url) {

                    yield new Request('GET', $url);

                }

        };


        $pool = new Pool($client, 
                        $requests($urls),

                        [
                            'concurrency' => 5,
                            'fulfilled' => function($response, $index) use ($urls){

                                echo "<br>Completed ".$urls[$index];

                            },

                            'rejected' => function($reason, $index){

                                echo "Rejected ".$index;


                            },
                        ]);


        $promise = $pool->promise();

        $promise->wait();
```

$urls is an array of URIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with a current implementation of the Guzzle Pool. The only thing you can possibly do with it is to `exit;` in the `fulfilled` function:

```
'fulfilled' => function($response, $index) use ($urls){
    echo "Completed " . $urls[$index];
    exit;
 },
```

In this case it will still send all the requests, but immediately exit the script on the fastest response.

Without the Pool you can use [GuzzleHttp\Promise\any](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/master/src/functions.php#L300) or [GuzzleHttp\Promise\some](https://github.com/guzzle/promises/blob/master/src/functions.php#L251) helper functions:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;

$client = new Client(['base_uri' => 'http://site.local/']);

// Initiate each request but do not block
$promises = [
    'delay3' => $client->getAsync('/async/delay3.php'),
    'delay2' => $client->getAsync('/async/delay2.php'),
    'delay1' => $client->getAsync('/async/delay1.php'),
];

//Initiate a competitive race between multiple promises
$promise = Promise\any($promises)->then(
    function (\GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response $response) {
        echo "Completed: " . $response->getStatusCode() . "\n";
        echo $response->getBody() ."\n";
    },
    function ($reason) {
        echo $reason;
    }
);

$results = $promise->wait();
```

From the docs for `GuzzleHttp\Promise\some($count, $promises)`:

> Initiate a competitive race between multiple promises or values
>   (values will  become immediately fulfilled promises).
>
> When count amount of promises have been fulfilled, the returned
>   promise is  fulfilled with an array that contains the fulfillment
>   values of the winners  in order of resolution.
>
> This promise is rejected with a {@see
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\AggregateException}  if the number of fulfilled
>   promises is less than the desired $count.

From the docs for `GuzzleHttp\Promise\any($promises)`:

> Like some(), with 1 as count. However, if the promise fulfills, the 
>   fulfillment value is not an array of 1 but the value directly.

Comment: Can you please explain, what any function actually is doing?

Comment: thank you for the reply! Btw, can give me a link of retry handler to use with this guzzle concurrent request

Comment: You can use retry middleware https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Middleware.php#L155 , not sure if this is what you need.